# Array of chars to linked list - Using the address in array

Tags: c, arrays, string, linked-list

i am trying to pass words from a string to a linked list, the thing is, i can't reallocate memory to my string inside my struct, i should be using the address of each word inside the array.

my struct:

```
typedef struct slist{
    char *string;
    struct slist * prox;
} *SList;
```

my function:

```
int towords (char t[], SList *l){
    int i, p;
    p=0;
    *l = (SList) calloc(1, sizeof(struct slist));

    SList aux = NULL;


    SList li = *l;
    for(i=0; t[i]!='\0' ;){
        aux = (SList) calloc(1, sizeof(struct slist));

        li->string = &t[i];
        li->prox = aux;
        li = aux;

        while(t[i]!=' ') i++;

        //t[i++] = '\0'; -> this doesn't work, bus error 10;

        while(t[i]==' ') i++;

        p++; //This counts words
    }

    return p;

}
```

This works, kind of, my doubt is, i can't change the initial array to include a NULL char at the end of each word (Strings declared in C are read-only right?)

So, i tried to add the t[i]='\0' in vain.

At this moment, running the code with this string

> char *str = "this is one sentence";

will get me the following strings in my linked list:

```
this is one sentence
is one sentence
one sentence
sentence
```

the expected result is not this one, it should add the NULL char after the first word inside my list->string

PS: The linked list is not well defined, it adds a NULL at the end unnecessarily but i can deal with that later on.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you need allocate for each word. then word copy to it.

Comment: use `char str[] = "this is on sentence";` which will create an array that you are allowed to modify. You should use const pointers for string literals `const char *str = "this is one sentence"` so the compiler will yell when you pass it as a non-const pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Can't copy, need to use the same address from the array, for each word. Copying would be far more easy.

Comment: @rpattiso will try to use an array like that

Comment: @skills You must be copied if it is not possible modified or use a string literal. also it is safe that it is not affected when the original sequence has been changed.

Comment: @skills you will need to add to your while loops so that they don't go beyond the end of the string `while (t[i] != '\0' && t[i] != ' ') i++;` and the same for the other while loop.

Comment: @rpattiso i noticed that :) but thank you for the warning. Your tip worked, in fact it does not work if i pass the address of a pointer, using str[] did the trick.

Comment: @rpattiso (will delete this comment) can you give the first comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to modify a string literal, which is why `t[i]='\0'` is failing in this case.

If you use `char str[] = "this is on sentence";` this will create an array that you are allowed to modify.

When using string literals in the future, you should use const pointers `const char *str = "this is one sentence"`,  this way the compiler would have complained when you tried to pass it to your `words` function as a non-const pointer/array.

Also add `t[i] != '\0'` to your while loops to stop them from going beyond the end of the array.  `while (t[i] != '\0' && t[i] != ' ') i++;`

While there is nothing wrong with storing pointers in a list, remember that they are only valid as long as the original array `str` passed to `words` is valid and not a string literal.

Comment: Yep, that last part got it :) . That mind-boggling detail, didn't knew a char pointer was pointing to a read only memory block.